# Excel formula - lookup with multiple criterias

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am exploring if there is a better formula for lookup with multiple criteria.

I have 2 sets of data so I need to merge two columns to find the value.

See data below.

**Set A**

```
Data1   Data2   Data3
SiteA   John    5
SiteB   Alvin   6
SiteA   Phil    7
SiteB   Albert  8
SiteA   Lucy    9
```

**Set B**

```
DataA   DataB
SiteA   John
SiteA   Alvin
SiteA   Phil
SiteA   Albert
SiteA   Lucy
SiteB   John
SiteB   Alvin
SiteA   Albert
```

**Result**

```
DataA   DataB   DataC
SiteA   John    5
SiteA   Alvin   #N/A
SiteA   Phil    7
SiteA   Albert  #N/A
SiteA   Lucy    9
SiteB   John    #N/A
SiteB   Alvin   6
SiteA   Albert  #N/A
```

`=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1,(G2=$A:$A)*(H2=$B:$B),0))` with Ctrl Shift Enter.

Just wonder if there is a better formula to achieve this? By using Ctrl Shift Enter, its taking a longer processing time on my machine that has 21000 rows.

Comment: Try referencing the actual ranges instead of using whole column references.  Also, if you convert your data into a Table, the ranges will automatically adjust as data is added or removed.

Comment: If `DataA` and  `DataB` combinedly do not repeat (eg. SiteA and John together appear only once) then an ugly/indirect way would be to use `=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,G2,B:B,H2)`